# is it possible to share a message when offline Open Graph API

Tags: php, post, facebook-opengraph

I have stored the `access_token` and `PageId` and i wanted to know is it possible to share a message when offline Open Graph API i mean using curl.

I am using below code

```
$page_id = 'XXXXXXXX';
$token = 'XXXXXXXXXX';
$app_namespace = 'test_app';
$ret_obj = $facebook->api('/'.$page_id .'/'.$app_namespace .':test','access_token'=>$token,'post', array(
                        'testing' => 'http://example.com/meta.php',
```

Even i had accessed offline_access too share isn't working.

Comment: Does the user that generated the access token (which is not an application token) have rights to publish to the page?

Answer (score 0):

The array you post must have a "message" element - you have "testing". This won't work as a facebook post does not have a testing element.

Maker sure you follow the documentation exactly!

Also, wrap your API calls in a try/catch block, and catch the errors. This gives you a clue as to what is going wrong.